# need help understanding event bubbling code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-bubbling

the following code was supposed to turn all the buttons present in the form into green color on one of the button clicks due to event bubbling, but on my machine on Visual studio 2008, it is turning only the clicked button as green, could you please help in figuring out the problem?

XAML Code (window1.xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="EventRouting.Window1" Title="Event Routing" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Border Margin="15" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5" Padding="15"
            CornerRadius="12" x:Name="myBorder" Background="Transparent">
<StackPanel x:Name="myPanel" Background="Transparent">
  <Ellipse x:Name="myEllipse" Margin="3" Fill="Green" Height="40" />
  <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" Margin="3" Fill="Cyan" Height="40" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

CS code (window1.xaml.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EventRouting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;
        myBorder.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;
        myPanel.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;
        myEllipse.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;
        myRectangle.MouseEnter += MouseEnterHandler;

        this.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;
        myBorder.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;
        myPanel.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;
        myEllipse.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;
        myRectangle.MouseDown += MouseDownHandler;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = "Button " + i;
            myPanel.Children.Add(btn);

            //btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
        }

        myPanel.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click));
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) e.Source;
        btn.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    void MouseEnterHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseEnter: " + sender);
    }
    void MouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseDown: " + sender);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routed events bubble up the visual tree until they get handled. Using your XAML, try this code out.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myEllipse.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseDown));
        myPanel.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseDown));
        myBorder.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMouseDown));
    }

    void OnMouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uiElement = sender as UIElement;
        Debug.WriteLine(uiElement.GetType().ToString());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

if you comment out the e.Handled = true line, the event will bubble up to parent elements.  Here is a good [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx#id0190038) for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want is a tunnel event from the root (the panel) to each child (the buttons). Routed tunnel events don't do that, they only traverse from the root to the the source element, not to siblings. See [Overview of routed events in WPF](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/overview-of-routed-events-in-wpf/) with a great illustration of this.

Answer (score 0):

Because the event handler btn_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) is sending the button you clicked only you can't use the sender object alone to change the text to green.

You should be doing something like `foreach (Button btn in myPanel.Children)` where you loop through all of your buttons and change the color in your loop.

Comment: but the event is getting added to myPanel (stackPanel), which keeps all the button, so it should get applied to all the buttons ?